# JavaFX custom scrollpane

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, scrollpane

I'm trying to implement a custom scrollpane in javafx. The main reason for this is, that I'd like to modify some visual parts as well as the scroll speed.
By the visual parts, I refer to the scrollbars that I want to hide after some time.

I did implement the scrollpane with the idea of clipping.
Thus I have a StackPane with a conent node, and I clip the StackPane. Scrolling is done by dragging the content node. So far no problem. What I want to achieve is that my scollpane adapts to the size of its parent (in my example an AnchorPane). Thus I "anchored" all the sides of my implementation, and listened to the scrollpanes layout bounds. 
Although my parent pane is limited to size (300,300) the scrollpane takes all the place. 
I think the main problem is with the layoutbounds. If you resize the window you will see the print-out is only written if the bounds exceed the diameter of the circle.

I'm open to any hints on how to best achieve a custom scrollpane.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class TestCase extends Application{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        private double NUM_IMAGES = 4.0;
        private Color col;



        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

            HBox hb = new HBox();


            hb.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(300,300));
    //      ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();

            TestScrollPane sp = new TestScrollPane();
            hb.getChildren().add(sp);

            sp.setContent(new StackPane(new Circle(400)));

            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(sp, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(sp, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(sp, 0.0);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(sp, 0.0);



            Scene scene = new Scene(hb,800,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("imdvistav5.css");



            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            primaryStage.show();




        }


        public class TestScrollPane extends StackPane{

            private AnchorPane content;
            private Rectangle clipRect;
            private MouseCoord coords;

            public TestScrollPane() {

                clipRect = new Rectangle(500,500);
                clipRect.setStyle("-fx-background-color:pink");
                setClip(clipRect);
                content = new AnchorPane();

                content.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        coords.set(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
                    }
                });

                content.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                        content.setTranslateX( content.getTranslateX()+ event.getScreenX()-coords.getX());
                        content.setTranslateY( content.getTranslateY()+ event.getScreenY()-coords.getY());
                        coords.set(event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());

                        System.out.println(getWidth());
                    }
                });
                coords = new MouseCoord();

                getChildren().add(content);



                layoutBoundsProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                    System.out.println(newValue.getWidth());
                    System.out.println(newValue.getHeight());
                    clipRect.setWidth(newValue.getWidth());
                    clipRect.setHeight(newValue.getHeight());
                  });   




            }

            public void setContent(Node node){
                content.getChildren().clear();
                content.getChildren().add(node);

                content.setTranslateX(0);content.setTranslateY(0);
            }

        }


        public class MouseCoord {


            private double x;
            private  double y;


            public MouseCoord() {

            }

            public MouseCoord(double x, double y) {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }
            public double getX() {
                return x;
            }
            public void setX(double x) {
                this.x = x;
            }
            public double getY() {
                return y;
            }
            public void setY(double y) {
                this.y = y;
            }

            public void set(double x, double y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
            }

        }

   }
```

Comment: I implemented my version of the scollpane with a VBox. I think, what you experiance is due to the `TestScrollPane` being a subclass of `StackPane`. There are subtile differences in the way content is layouted, which happens when the size changes. I would suggest, you use a `Group` or `Pane` as super class instead. Also have a look at this article about layouting: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

Comment: I already checked the documentation. However, with a simple pane it works more or less as expected. I decided to copy the original scrollpane code and to modify it to my needs.